# Select Max INT without leading edge zeros

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue with a database query. I'm trying to select the max value of a table, but unfortunately the table doesn't have leading zeros in place. The id numbers in the field just went from 9999 to 10000, but when I try to get MAX('id'), it **returns 9999 instead of 10000**. I assume this issue is due to the fact that the 9999 is not 09999. Some simple googling doesn't seem to answer this issue, most of the results I get are how to remove leading zeros from the SQL search, not how to handle if they are not there.

```
SELECT MAX(id) as MaxID FROM Orders
```

Is there a way to select the max value when there are no leading edge zeros?

Comment: There is certainly not a problem when there is not a leading zero when the datatype is a number. What datatype is your column id?

Comment: (As I commented below) It didn't even occur to me to check what the field was set as, it was set to VarChar afterall... doh! Now I feel dumb... All the other instances in the database to this number on other tables were set to INT, so I guess I just assumed it was INT. Setting it to INT fixed everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to understand the problem -- storing a numeric value as a string changes how the values are sorted.

You can convert to a number by adding a zero:

```
SELECT MAX(id+0) as MaxID
FROM Orders;
```

Or, you can get the maximum with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
select o.*
from orders o
order by length(id) desc, id desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: It didn't even occur to me to check what the field was set as, it was set to VarChar afterall... doh! All the other instances in the database to this number on other tables were set to INT, so I guess I just assumed it was INT. Setting it to INT fixed everything. Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: I will set this to the correct answer once it allows me to in about 8 minutes.

Comment: "you can convert to a number by converting to a number". Tautology?

Comment: @Barmar . . . Yes, that is a tautology.  Rather useless too.  I think I wanted to put in something about "silent conversion".